I accidentally published an npm package with a different account and unpublished, can I republish again on my main account?
The question is self-explanatory. I accidentally published mypackage version 1.0.0 on a different account. I realized this within a few minutes and ran npm unpublish mypackage --force to remove this.
Now I've logged into my main account and bumped up the version to 1.0.1. I can't republish yet because of the 24 hour rule, but once that passes, will I be able to publish using my main account? I lost access to the different account's email, so really can't access it at all.
